# Creating a user having only access to folder & sub-folder which is present in other user of the same System

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, permissions, users, account-restrictions

I have 2 users on my ubuntu system, User1 and User2.

I have a directory(folder) in User1 as `/home/User1/Software` and I want to set this Software folder as home directory of User2 so that whenever user2 logins he can see only Software folder that too only with read access to it.

If we remotely login to that system through User2 we are directly migrated to software folder with only read rights and can't access any other folder except Software and its sub-folder.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change User2's account so that it uses a restricted shell such as `rbash`.

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/rbash User2
```

NOTE: this will only restrict the user's command-line shell (including logging in via `ssh`).  It will not affect their GUI desktop environment e.g. if they log in on the console.

See `man rbash` for more details but some of the restrictions are that the user is prevented from:

> · changing directories with cd
>
> · setting or unsetting the values of SHELL, PATH, ENV, or BASH_ENV
>
> · specifying command names containing /
>
> · specifying  a  filename  containing  a / as an argument to the . builtin command
>
> · redirecting output using the >, >|, <>, >&, &>, and >> redirection operators
>
> · using the exec builtin command to replace the shell with another command
>
> These restrictions are enforced after any startup files are read.

Blocking redirection may be excessive for your needs (or maybe not since the directory is readonly anyway), but unfortunately with `rbash` it's all or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

**How to Prevent a User From Seeing Any Files Under the `/home` Directory Except Their Own**

Accomplish this by managing file permissions on the directories that you don't want the user to see.

Give the user a unique login name and group name.  Check that they have no ownership on the system; get their numeric user id and group id and run:

```
sudo find / -uid n -o -gid n
```

Make all files under `/home` accessible only to `user` and `group`, not `other`.

```
sudo chmod -R o-rwx /home
```

To allow the other users on the system to see each others' files under `/home`, add them all to a common group, such as `users`, and set their `umask` to 002 (usually the default).

If you need more restrictions than this, you may investigate solutions involving rbash and/or chroot.